# Estoy intentando eliminar el margin, padding de mi html pero por alguna razón si no se lo "quito" a todas las secciones no me lo hace

Tags: html, css

Aquí el código

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  `` padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>SkyWeb</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Menu nav -->

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#structure">Day structure</a></li>
      <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#schedule">Schedule</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!-- header ironsky -->
  <header>
    <h1><img src=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ih-materials/uploads/ironhack-skydive-logo.png alt="IronSkydive Logo">IronSkydive</h1>
    <h2>Let the trip begin</h2>
    <!-- cite -->
    <aside>"The best experience of our lives"<br> Ariel Quiñones&Gonzalo Manrique,Ironhacks Founders
    </aside>
  </header>

  <!-- section one -->
  <section id="general-information">

    <!-- article one -->
    <article>
      <h3>Hello!</h3>
      <p>Welcome to IronSkydive,the best adventure you will ever have.</p>
      <a href="#learn">Learn More</a>
    </article>

    <!-- article two -->
    <article>
      <h3>About us</h3>
      <p>We like a lot programming websites,but we also love to practice sport.</p>
      <a href="#watch">Watch Video</a>
    </article>

    <!-- article three -->
    <article>
      <h3>Wanna join?</h3>
      <p>Join our fitness program to be in good shape while learning.</p>
      <a href="#user">Register</a>
    </article>

  </section>
  <!-- section two -->
  <section id="structure">
    <h3>How do we structure the day?</h3>
    <div>
      <!-- article one section two-->
      <article>
        <img src=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ih-materials/uploads/ironskydive-training.png>
        <h4>1. Training</h4>
        <p>We teach all the necessary things to jump from the plane without any kind of problem.</p>
      </article>

      <!-- article two section two-->
      <article>
        <img src=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ih-materials/uploads/ironskydive-get-ready.png>
        <h4>2. Get ready</h4>
        <p>You are already prepared,you just need the suit and a parachute.All sizes available</p>
      </article>

      <!-- article three section two-->
      <article>
        <img src=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ih-materials/uploads/ironskydive-fly.png>
        <h4>3. Fly</h4>
        <p>You are ready,and the plane is waiting for us in the hangar.Let´s fly!</p>
      </article>

      <!-- article four section two-->
      <article>
        <img src=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ih-materials/uploads/ironskydive-jump.png>
        <h4>4. Jump!</h4>
        <p>You have done the most complicated.Just one setp left...jump!</p>
      </article>

    </div>
  </section>



  <!-- section three -->
  <section id="team">
    <h3>Team</h3>
    <p>Our team collectively has 75 years of exprience.Odds are, when you jump out of the plane with these professinoals,you won´t go splat.</p>

    <div>
      <!-- article one -->
      <article>
        <h4>Harold Rothstein</h4>
        <img src=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ih-materials/uploads/upload_c18b1c463b80090894237a262dfdfbad.jpg>
      </article>

      <!-- article two -->
      <article>
        <h4>Susan Phillips</h4>
        <img src=h ttps://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ih-materials/uploads/upload_a18d6123a7c8e75f7e70a4e59b941093.jpg>
      </article>

      <!-- article three -->
      <article>
        <h4>Taylor Roberts</h4>
        <img src=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ih-materials/uploads/upload_7104a331530d1b0611da55093b7dc421.jpg>
      </article>
    </div>

  </section>

  <!-- section four -->

  <section id="schedule">
    <h3>Schedule</h3>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <!-- Schedule ironsky -->
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thusday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
        <th>Saturday</th>
      </thead>
      <!-- first row -->
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>09:00 - 11:00</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>X</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>X</td>
          <td>X</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>

      <!-- second row -->
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>12:00 - 14:00</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>X</td>
          <td>X</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>

      <!-- three row -->
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>15:00 - 17:00</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>X</td>
          <td>X</td>
          <td>X</td>
          <td>X</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>

    </table>
    <h3>Schedule a Time Slot</h3>
  </section>


  <!-- footer -->

  <footer>
    <section>
      <h5>Contact Information</h5>
      <br>
      <address>IronSkydive<br>
                     33 Rue la Fayette,<br>
                     75009 Paris,<br>
                     France<br>
                     +33(0)619193088
            </address>

      <h5>Follow Us</h5>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#twi">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#fb">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="ig">Instagram</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

Solo si le aplico el `margin:0` y `padding:0` a todo el css me elimina los espacios, es decir, se lo tengo que aplicar al `li`, todas las `h`, al `p`, etc... Entonces no sé por qué no lo hace ya que yo se lo estoy aplicando a todo el html y body, no me elimina el margin. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Puede que te fallara antes porque en el código original tenías dos acentos justo después del margin? margin:0;``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 3.5em;
  `introducir el código aquí` weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>SkyWeb</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Menu nav -->

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#structure">Day structure</a></li>
      <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#schedule">Schedule</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!-- header ironsky -->
  <header>
    <h1><img src=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ih-materials/uploads/ironhack-skydive-logo.png alt="IronSkydive Logo">IronSkydive</h1>
    <h2>Let the trip begin</h2>
    <!-- cite -->
    <aside>"The best experience of our lives"<br> Ariel Quiñones&Gonzalo Manrique,Ironhacks Founders
    </aside>
  </header>

  <!-- section one -->
  <section id="general-information">

    <!-- article one -->
    <article>
      <h3>Hello!</h3>
      <p>Welcome to IronSkydive,the best adventure you will ever have.</p>
      <a href="#learn">Learn More</a>
    </article>

    <!-- article two -->
    <article>
      <h3>About us</h3>
      <p>We like a lot programming websites,but we also love to practice sport.</p>
      <a href="#watch">Watch Video</a>
    </article>

    <!-- article three -->
    <article>
      <h3>Wanna join?</h3>
      <p>Join our fitness program to be in good shape while learning.</p>
      <a href="#user">Register</a>
    </article>

  </section>
  <!-- section two -->
  <section id="structure">
    <h3>How do we structure the day?</h3>
    <div>
      <!-- article one section two-->
      <article>
        <img src=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ih-materials/uploads/ironskydive-training.png>
        <h4>1. Training</h4>
        <p>We teach all the necessary things to jump from the plane without any kind of problem.</p>
      </article>

      <!-- article two section two-->
      <article>
        <img src=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ih-materials/uploads/ironskydive-get-ready.png>
        <h4>2. Get ready</h4>
        <p>You are already prepared,you just need the suit and a parachute.All sizes available</p>
      </article>

      <!-- article three section two-->
      <article>
        <img src=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ih-materials/uploads/ironskydive-fly.png>
        <h4>3. Fly</h4>
        <p>You are ready,and the plane is waiting for us in the hangar.Let´s fly!</p>
      </article>

      <!-- article four section two-->
      <article>
        <img src=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ih-materials/uploads/ironskydive-jump.png>
        <h4>4. Jump!</h4>
        <p>You have done the most complicated.Just one setp left...jump!</p>
      </article>

    </div>
  </section>



  <!-- section three -->
  <section id="team">
    <h3>Team</h3>
    <p>Our team collectively has 75 years of exprience.Odds are, when you jump out of the plane with these professinoals,you won´t go splat.</p>

    <div>
      <!-- article one -->
      <article>
        <h4>Harold Rothstein</h4>
        <img src=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ih-materials/uploads/upload_c18b1c463b80090894237a262dfdfbad.jpg>
      </article>

      <!-- article two -->
      <article>
        <h4>Susan Phillips</h4>
        <img src=h ttps://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ih-materials/uploads/upload_a18d6123a7c8e75f7e70a4e59b941093.jpg>
      </article>

      <!-- article three -->
      <article>
        <h4>Taylor Roberts</h4>
        <img src=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ih-materials/uploads/upload_7104a331530d1b0611da55093b7dc421.jpg>
      </article>
    </div>

  </section>

  <!-- section four -->

  <section id="schedule">
    <h3>Schedule</h3>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <!-- Schedule ironsky -->
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thusday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
        <th>Saturday</th>
      </thead>
      <!-- first row -->
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>09:00 - 11:00</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>X</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>X</td>
          <td>X</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>

      <!-- second row -->
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>12:00 - 14:00</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>X</td>
          <td>X</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>

      <!-- three row -->
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>15:00 - 17:00</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>X</td>
          <td>X</td>
          <td>X</td>
          <td>X</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>

    </table>
    <h3>Schedule a Time Slot</h3>
  </section>


  <!-- footer -->

  <footer>
    <section>
      <h5>Contact Information</h5>
      <br>
      <address>IronSkydive<br>
                     33 Rue la Fayette,<br>
                     75009 Paris,<br>
                     France<br>
                     +33(0)619193088
            </address>

      <h5>Follow Us</h5>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#twi">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#fb">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="ig">Instagram</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

no se porque pero ahora he conseguido lo que quería

Comment: Para resetear los *márgenes*, *paddings* y *borders* a **0** de tu documento, podrías añadir esta línea al principio de tu **CSS** ```* { border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; }```, luego **weight: 300** cámbialo por ```font-weight: 300;```, aquí te dejo una respuesta de SOes donde puedes ver mejor como resetear las etiquetas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/527493/problema-con-el-margen-en-css/527516#527516